# How do i change cell values with PHPExcel without change cell's style?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm writting a web application that modify some cells of an already existing excel's file, i'm using PHPExcel to do that, but when i use the setValue function of a cell, it clean the style of the cell. Also i tried using `getActiveSheet()->setCellValue` but it also clean the cell's style.

How i can change the cell's value without touching it style? It is possible with PHPExcel? Thanks.

**Edit**: The existing file has it cells formated with background color, borders, format of numbers, etc, and when i edit the cell value with PHPExcel, all of that is deleted and replaced with a blank cell with the value that i set, I want to conserve the style/format of the cell when i set it value, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally i found the answer, here: http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/213643

**setCellValue** & **setValue** appears to create a new cell and place it over the old one, but if you use **setCellValueByColumnAndRow** your old cell style and format will be conserved!

tl;dr: Use **setCellValueByColumnAndRow** instead.

Comment: Shouldn't make any difference.... if you look at the actual code in the PHPExcel_Worksheet class, you'll see they do exactly the same thing

Comment: Thanks, I was searching for this. I'll try it tomorrow.